# Updating ListView Adapter from AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, adapter

what I have is an `AsyncTask,` that started as soon as `ListView` reached bottom item on a screen, and in `AsyncTask` it adds new items to the `ListView.`

Here is the code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final List<ItemDailyRecord> records) {
        super.onPostExecute(records);
        ((ActivityHome)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                for (ItemDailyRecord p : records) {
                    adapter.add(p);
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }

 @Override
    protected List<ItemDailyRecord> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        DbAdapterDailyRecord db = new DbAdapterDailyRecord(context);
        List<ItemDailyRecord> list = db.getRecordsFromTo(offset, count);

        return list;
    }
```

here is a method from ListView Adapter:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(position == getCount() - 1 && hasMoreItems){
            HistoryLoaderTask t = new HistoryLoaderTask(position + 1, pageSize, getContext(),this);
            t.execute();
            footer.setText("Loading . . .");
        }
```

And the error message is(if I scroll the listview too fast :)

> Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException:
>   Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
>   views.

any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: `onPostExecute()` already runs in UI thread. The `runOnUiThread()` call is useless.

Comment: Show the code you are using in doInBackground

Comment: but if I remove it, error message is also there :(

Comment: also, shouldnt you add the item to a list that is referenced to that adapter rather than the adapter itself?

Comment: I updated my post with "doInBackground" method.

Answer (score 1):

The `onPostExecute()` method is executed on the UI thread, so you should be updating the UI directly in this method; no need to spawn a new `Runnable` object.

Comment: but even I update UI directly, I run into:Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: What is the type of your `ListView` adapter?

Comment: public class AdapterHistoryList extends ArrayAdapter<ItemDailyRecord>

Comment: may be its related on Fragments I am using, so that on the UI thread is not properly called. Because in my code I have an Activity "ActivityHome" and there I dynamicly load a Fragment "MyFragment extends SherlockFragment". In this "MyFragment" I have listview, adapter etc...

Comment: It's not obvious to me that that would be the source of the issue. If you run it in the debugger, and set a breakpoint inside `getView()` and inside `onPostExecute()`, you should be able to see which thread is executing these method. It **should** be the UI thread, which will be marked as `<main>` in the Eclipse debug window. If it's not, see if you can track down (mabye through the stack trace) what is spawning this other thread.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't execute your async task from getView of your adapter. Instead you should try to do it from your activity/fragment where your list resides by using getLastVisiblePosition() of ListView

Like this --->

```
if(list.getLastVisiblePosition() == (dataSet.size() - 1)) {
// last item displayed
.... change the text off footer and execute async task
}
```

and in the async task append the extra data to dataset and then call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter.